# Lista de chamada + Inscritos e participantes por evento

Tags: php, mysql, join, count

Tenho as seguintes tabelas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso listar EMPRESAS e INSCRITOS NO EVENTO (que pode ter mais de uma palestra) e na mesma linha trazer a QTD DE PRESENTES por palestra em colunas... Assim conseguiria um parâmetro de aproveitamento por palestra em específico para cada empresa participante.

As presenças em cada palestra são registradas no `e_presenca` via `cod_incsricao`. Esse código é validado pelo `e_inscrito`. Se o inscrito está cadastrado, a presença é incluida. ( salvando o INSCRITO `cod_inscricao` / EVENTO `evento` / PALESTRA `id_evento` / EMPRESA `empresa`)

O q consegui até agora foi uma tabela nada dinâmica e números irreais com o seguinte SQL, O que estou fazendo de errado? Ou o que deveria reestruturar nessas tabelas (já populadas)?

```
SELECT ins.empresa, COUNT(ins.empresa) Inscritos,
COUNT(CASE WHEN  pre.id_evento = '32' THEN 0 ELSE NULL END) AS UM,
COUNT(CASE WHEN  pre.id_evento = '25' THEN 0 ELSE NULL END) AS DOIS
FROM e_presenca pre
INNER JOIN e_inscrito ins ON ins.empresa = pre.empresa
WHERE ins.id_evento = '18' 
GROUP BY ins.empresa
```

Os nomes das empresas estão realmente em txt e não em numero/id (alterei por exemplo). 
Na tabela `e_presença` a tupla `evento` faz o papel do grupo e `id_evento` faz o de sub-grupo (que acaba sendo um espelho da tabela `evento`)

Comment: Por favor, explique, na pergunta, a estrutura das suas tabelas, pois não parecem estar normalizadas. Por exemplo, mas não se limite apenas a, por quê nas tabelas `e_inscrito` e `e_presenca` o que aparece é o nome da empresa e não o id? Em `e_presenca`, qual a diferença entre `evento` e `id_evento`?

Comment: Certo, vou editar. 
Quanto aos nomes em `e_inscrito` e `e_presenca` ao invés dos ids, é que estes já foram recebidos dessa forma.
na tabela `e_presenca`, evento faz o papel do grupo e id_evento o de sub-grupo

Comment: @ItaFilho primeiramente, não entendi porque na coluna `empresa` das tabelas `e_inscrito` e `e_presenca`, não está trazendo o `id` da tabela `e_empresas`, não me parece apenas exibição. Outra coisa, para ajudar a te ajudarmos, public no http://sqlfiddle.com/ a estrutura para que possamos testar o select que você precisa, se não de cabeça, toma mais tempo e pode até conter erros bobos que acabam passando.

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi muito sua estrutura, se você tiver como normalizar ficaria muito melhor...

Montei um exemplo (sql server) que você pode testar e avaliar se te ajuda:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPRESA
(
    ID_EMPRESA INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    EMPRESA VARCHAR(255)
)

CREATE TABLE EVENTO
(
    ID_EVENTO INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    CATEGORIA VARCHAR(255),
    TITULO VARCHAR(255),
    PALESTRANTE VARCHAR(255)
)

CREATE TABLE E_INSCRITO
(
    ID_INSCRITO INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    ID_EMPRESA INT,
    ID_EVENTO INT,
    COD_INSCRICAO VARCHAR(50),
    PRESENCA BIT DEFAULT NULL
)

-- ### Empresa ### --
INSERT INTO EMPRESA (EMPRESA) VALUES ('Empresa 1')
INSERT INTO EMPRESA (EMPRESA) VALUES ('Empresa 2')
INSERT INTO EMPRESA (EMPRESA) VALUES ('Empresa 3')
INSERT INTO EMPRESA (EMPRESA) VALUES ('Empresa 4')
INSERT INTO EMPRESA (EMPRESA) VALUES ('Empresa 5')
--------------------

-- ### Evento ### --
INSERT INTO EVENTO (CATEGORIA, TITULO, PALESTRANTE) VALUES ('Evento 1', 'Palestra 1', 'Palestrante 1')
INSERT INTO EVENTO (CATEGORIA, TITULO, PALESTRANTE) VALUES ('Evento 2', 'Palestra 2', 'Palestrante 1')
INSERT INTO EVENTO (CATEGORIA, TITULO, PALESTRANTE) VALUES ('Evento 3', 'Palestra 3', 'Palestrante 1')
INSERT INTO EVENTO (CATEGORIA, TITULO, PALESTRANTE) VALUES ('Evento 4', 'Palestra 4', 'Palestrante 2')
INSERT INTO EVENTO (CATEGORIA, TITULO, PALESTRANTE) VALUES ('Evento 5', 'Palestra 5', 'Palestrante 2')
INSERT INTO EVENTO (CATEGORIA, TITULO, PALESTRANTE) VALUES ('Evento 6', 'Palestra 6', 'Palestrante 2')
--------------------

-- ### Inscritos ### --
INSERT INTO E_INSCRITO (ID_EMPRESA, ID_EVENTO, COD_INSCRICAO, PRESENCA) VALUES (1, 1, '100', 0)
INSERT INTO E_INSCRITO (ID_EMPRESA, ID_EVENTO, COD_INSCRICAO, PRESENCA) VALUES (1, 1, '101', 0)
INSERT INTO E_INSCRITO (ID_EMPRESA, ID_EVENTO, COD_INSCRICAO, PRESENCA) VALUES (1, 2, '102', NULL)
INSERT INTO E_INSCRITO (ID_EMPRESA, ID_EVENTO, COD_INSCRICAO, PRESENCA) VALUES (1, 3, '103', 1)

INSERT INTO E_INSCRITO (ID_EMPRESA, ID_EVENTO, COD_INSCRICAO, PRESENCA) VALUES (2, 1, '200', 1)
INSERT INTO E_INSCRITO (ID_EMPRESA, ID_EVENTO, COD_INSCRICAO, PRESENCA) VALUES (2, 1, '201', 1)
INSERT INTO E_INSCRITO (ID_EMPRESA, ID_EVENTO, COD_INSCRICAO, PRESENCA) VALUES (2, 1, '202', 0)
INSERT INTO E_INSCRITO (ID_EMPRESA, ID_EVENTO, COD_INSCRICAO, PRESENCA) VALUES (2, 3, '203', 1)
INSERT INTO E_INSCRITO (ID_EMPRESA, ID_EVENTO, COD_INSCRICAO, PRESENCA) VALUES (2, 4, '204', NULL)

INSERT INTO E_INSCRITO (ID_EMPRESA, ID_EVENTO, COD_INSCRICAO, PRESENCA) VALUES (3, 1, '300', 0)
INSERT INTO E_INSCRITO (ID_EMPRESA, ID_EVENTO, COD_INSCRICAO, PRESENCA) VALUES (3, 4, '301', NULL)
INSERT INTO E_INSCRITO (ID_EMPRESA, ID_EVENTO, COD_INSCRICAO, PRESENCA) VALUES (3, 6, '302', 1)
INSERT INTO E_INSCRITO (ID_EMPRESA, ID_EVENTO, COD_INSCRICAO, PRESENCA) VALUES (3, 6, '303', 1)
INSERT INTO E_INSCRITO (ID_EMPRESA, ID_EVENTO, COD_INSCRICAO, PRESENCA) VALUES (3, 6, '304', 1)

INSERT INTO E_INSCRITO (ID_EMPRESA, ID_EVENTO, COD_INSCRICAO, PRESENCA) VALUES (4, 4, '400', NULL)
INSERT INTO E_INSCRITO (ID_EMPRESA, ID_EVENTO, COD_INSCRICAO, PRESENCA) VALUES (4, 5, '401', 1)
INSERT INTO E_INSCRITO (ID_EMPRESA, ID_EVENTO, COD_INSCRICAO, PRESENCA) VALUES (4, 6, '402', 1)

INSERT INTO E_INSCRITO (ID_EMPRESA, ID_EVENTO, COD_INSCRICAO, PRESENCA) VALUES (5, 5, '500', 1)
INSERT INTO E_INSCRITO (ID_EMPRESA, ID_EVENTO, COD_INSCRICAO, PRESENCA) VALUES (5, 5, '501', 1)
-----------------------



SELECT TITULO, EMPRESA, CASE WHEN PRESENCA = 1 THEN 'Confirmado' WHEN PRESENCA = 0 THEN 'Não confirmado' ELSE 'Não informado' END PRESENCA, COUNT(ISNULL(PRESENCA, 0)) TOTAL_PRESENCA
FROM E_INSCRITO
INNER JOIN EMPRESA ON EMPRESA.ID_EMPRESA = E_INSCRITO.ID_EMPRESA
INNER JOIN EVENTO ON EVENTO.ID_EVENTO = E_INSCRITO.ID_EVENTO
GROUP BY TITULO, EMPRESA, PRESENCA
ORDER BY TITULO, EMPRESA, PRESENCA
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/27e79/1

Comment: Interessante! Ao ver seu exemplo funcionar, notei uma falha no formato formato das tabelas que tenho (q infelizmente já foram  populadas dessa forma e é o que  tenho em mãos no momento).

Estou quase lá... vou reeditar minha pergunta. 
Obrigado pela ajuda!